# Keep CKAN running in background

Tags: ckan

I just finished installing CKAN from source and datapusher on my ubuntu 16.04 server. They are installed in Python virtual environment.

Currently I start datapusher using

> JOB_CONFIG='/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/deployment/datapusher_settings.py' python /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/wsgi.py

and CKAN using

> paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini

I am wondering if CKAN providers some commands to keep them running in the background after I close the terminal window.

Thanks,

Chen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [install instructions for source](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html), which you followed im assuming, sets up CKAN to run in development mode by default.  It also has links to instructions for datapusher and datastore.

To get CKAN to run in the "background" you can deploy CKAN using a different web server that runs as a service. One of the easiest ways for a source install is to follow the [Deployment instructions here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/deployment.html). It will walk you through installing Apache and Nginx and configuring CKAN to run on these.

The installation you've currently done is basically step 1, now just follow step 2 which is deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add '& disown' at the end of the command to run it as like a daemon

`paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini& disown`

It will help you to run the process in the background even if the terminal was closed.